# How to prepare a high level plan for a 1 week Design Engagement

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, ux-field

I am trying to prepare a high-level plan and approach for leading a 1-week Design Engagement for a Healthcare company, with a use case focused on improving the experience and outcomes of patients who need physical therapy rehabilitation.

Following is the draft plan:

**DAY 01: PREPARATION & UX RESEARCH**
Goal: Understand users

MORNING
- Introduction, Ice breaker

- Activity 01 (30 minutes): Stakholder Map. Work out the relationships of the stakeholders to each other and to the project.
- Activity 02 (30 minutes): Stakeholder Hopes and Fears. Expectations and expected challenges.
- Summary (60 minutes)

AFTERNOON

- Activity 02 (half a day): Lunch and onsite visit to facility. Observe, talk and understand patients.
- Summary (60 minutes)

**DAY 02: Ideation**
Goal: come up with ideas

MORNING
- Activity 01 (60 minutes): Empathy Map. Work out complete portrait of users.

- Activity 02 (60 minutes): User Stories
- Summary (60 minutes)

AFTERNOON
- Activity 03 (60 minutes): Big Idea Vignettes. Idea-brainstorming session.

- Activity 04: (60 minutes): Prioritize Grid. Finalize key ideas
- Summary (60 minutes)

**DAY 03: Wireframe/Prototype**
Goal: Build simple and refined models

MORNING:

- Early morning onsite visit (30–60 minute)
- Activity 01: Sketching/Low-fidelity wireframe (60 minutes). Come up with simple models for key ideas
- Activity 02: Presenting ideas and feedback (60 minutes)

AFTERNOON:

- Activity 03: Medium-fidelity wireframe (60 minutes). Refine built models.
- Activity 04: Presenting ideas and feedback (60 minutes)
- Summary (60 minutes)

**DAY 04: Wireframe/Prototype**
Goal: Build simple and refined models

MORNING:

- Testing with patients (120 minutes)
- Summary (60 minutes)

AFTERNOON:

- Activity 01: High-fidelity wireframe/Prototype (60 minutes)
- Activity 02: Presenting ideas and feedback (60 minutes)
- Summary (60 minutes)

**DAY 05: Testing/Feedback**

MORNING:

- Testing with patients (120 minutes)
- Summary (60 minutes)

AFTERNOON:

- Program Summary and feedback (120 minutes)

**NOTES:**
- This is a week draft plan of Design Engagement activity excluding logistic pre/post-program preparation.

- The activities should be reviewed and re-planned everyday if needed. There are extra matarials for activities like storyboard, need statement,etc. when required.
- The program will be held at a real-life physical-therapy facility. -
- Participants should try to live and see things from the patients’ angle to have more insights and provide better solutions to improve thier lives.

**QUESTIONS:**
- Kindly give me some comments over the draft plan above. Especially about the type of activities, the order, the amount of allocated time for each activity.

- What could be potential challenges I might face organizing program like this? Especially with the target audience as physical therapy patients.
- How to make the activities more lively and fun? Fun and productivity do go along really well; especially when it comes to creative tasks such as these.
- The activities are planned based on IBM’s design thinking guideline. What other guideline could be used? Any book recommendations?
- How to make this plan more “high level”? Does a “high level” plan include logistic pre/post-program and contingency plan?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the participants are employees of the healthcare company and that they have some relationship with the physical therapy center, which is why the company has permission to hold the workshop at the center.

I found that testing with users who are healthcare clients and patients is a tricky process even though the people involved might have given the go-ahead. 
First off, there are privacy concerns: do you have consent forms for the test participants? They are receiving health treatment and they need to know that participation is voluntary and anonymous. And if you are in the US, there's HIPAA/health info privacy laws to be aware off.

Best to have someone in the healthcare company legal department run through the details of the patient participation section and clear it to avoid any last minute catches.

Comment: I agree. There is some pre-work here to ensure things go as planned. Are you going to record?

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for the tips. Getting consent from participants could be a major issue. In case we cannot, I am hoping to get those who know the patients really well like caretakers to give their opinion during the process.

Running through this with Healthcare company would be the first thing we do after finalizing this draft plan. Thanks

@JoshuaLowry: Recording has not been in my plan yet. Would you think there will be a lot of works to prepare and execute? I am not sure clients will approve of this though.

Comment: Recording is very important for bring able to craft there story for anyone who want there. You will want consent forms for this also. They may have a data privacy contact who can help. If your doing observations then video is better, audio can give you a ton by itself. Take pictures if possible to bring back to the room.

Comment: One challenge with proxy is that you may be wrong. You should be upfront about this in your plan.

Comment: Checking with the healthcare facility is important too - maybe it won't be such a big deal or they can identify patients who don't have an issue with participating or they have a good rapport with. You can explain how this research will end up benefiting the patient. Recording is always a good idea but there has to be a consent form and the participants know how the information will be used. I think it's important to communicate this to participants, especially if they are volunteers.  Usually people are more than happy to give feedback if they know how it can eventually benefit them.